# Replacing ones and zeros with factor value

Tags: r, replace, dplyr

I have a data set with a column where each row either has a one or a zero. I need to change all zeros to a factor "s", and all ones to factor "ns". It doesn't seem difficult but i cant figure it out, pleas help!

Comment: `a <- c(0, 1); a[a == 0] <- "s"; a[a == 1] <- "ns"`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `factor` approach.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(.fns = ~factor(.x, c(0, 1), c('s', 'ns'))))

#   a  b
#1  s ns
#2  s ns
#3  s ns
#4 ns  s
#5  s  s
```

Or using `lapply` in base R -

```
df[] <- lapply(df, factor, c(0, 1), c('s', 'ns'))
```

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(a = sample(c(0, 1), 5, replace = TRUE) ,
                 b = sample(c(0, 1), 5, replace = TRUE))
df
#  a b
#1 0 1
#2 0 1
#3 0 1
#4 1 0
#5 0 0
```